# Full screen Background

Tags: html, css

i Want my background image to completely fil in the browser window. I tried css

```
body {background:url(bg.jpg) fixed no-repeat 100%}
```

but its not covering entire screen.

Answer (score 4):

```
css: 
background-size: cover;
```

is what you are looking for i guess.
for cross borswer support try this:
CSS:

```
 html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

source:
[css tricks full page background](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 0):

I use backstretch.js to fit backgrounds to window size. It's jquery, obviously, but it's very reliable from my experience.

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score 0):

create an id for the img tag and the following formatting

```
#background {
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS:

```
background: url(yourImage) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

This pins (fix) the picture andalso stretches it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want cross browser including IE try this method:

```
        theWindow.resize(function() {
            resizeBg();
        }).trigger("resize");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/A5ZNy/

Which is also mentioned in csstricks:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/jquery.php